# Prevent syneresis effect in agar-agar fruit jam

Tags: jam, pectin

I'm trying to make strawberry jam with agar-agar as replacement of pectin, where for it I'm using 0,4% of agar (of final product). I have read in many places that by replacing 0.1-0.2% of agar with locust beam gum is possible to prevent syneresis effect. My problem is that I tried but it does not work very well. After a single day water starts to show up. On the contrary, the same recipe but with pectin is syneresis free. So, is it possible to totally prevent syneresis using agar-agar?

Comment: You *might* be able to reduce the syneresis using a humectant such as glycerin or sorbitol: https://www.google.com/search?q=glycerin+humectant+syneresis&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8 I've not tried this with agar, but it helps with eg tapioca.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, syneresis is a byproduct of an agar gel.  It is the nature of the molecular structure formed in the gel.  This can be desirable, especially when using agar as a clarifying agent, however, not good for your jam.  According to www.molecularrecipes.com, you can prevent this by replacing 0.1 - 0.2 percent agar with locust bean gum. I see you've tried this, but it is the common wisdom/suggestion. Maybe up the lbg a little? Alternate thickeners are gelatin, arrowroot or chia seeds.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Do you know if the syneresis effect continues with time. If I leave it for a month, for example, will the jam be totally liquid?

Comment: @Miguel the solids will be left behind, the clear liquid will be flavored.  It will happen in days/hours (depending), as opposed to weeks.